# jquery ajax method being repeated even though click event not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dom-manipulation

I have some ajax on my web page, that is triggered via a click event,  the javascript in question looks like this,

```
$('.career_select .selectitems').click(function(){
        var selectedCareer = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/roadmap/step_two',
            data: 'career_choice='+selectedCareer+"&ajax=true&submit_career=Next",
            success: function(html){
                $('.hfeed').append(html);
                buildSelects();
                $('.grade_options .selectitems').addClass('select_1')
              }
        });
    });
```

This part of the ajax request works fine. What happens on success is that I load in another view into my page, this view has some more user interaction that fires some more ajax however, it just fires the previously used method, where as it should be doing the following,

```
    $('.grade_options .selectitems').click(function(){
    var selectedGrade = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(selectedGrade);
})
```

The HTML+PHP looks like this,

```
<div class="grade_options">
        <input value="" name="grade" class="customselect" type="hidden">
        <div class="iconselect">Have you got any of the following?</div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="iconselectholder"> 
        <div class="selectoptions"> 
            <div id="1" class="selectitems hoverclass selectedclass select_1">
                <span>Accountant</span>
            </div>
            <div id="2" class="selectitems">
                <span> Grade D's at GCSE including English and Maths</span>
            </div>
            <div id="3" class="selectitems">
                <span>3 GCSE's at grade B and 3 GCSEs at grade C or equivalent and you must have achieved at least a grade C in GCSE English Language &amp; B in Maths</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
                <noscript>
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit_grades" class="arr" />
                </noscript>
</div>
```

The .selectitems get created from a select menu using this plugin,

```
    $.fn.customSelect = function() {
  // define defaults and override with options, if available
  // by extending the default settings, we don't modify the argument
 return this.each(function() {  
 obj = $(this);  
obj.after("<div class=\"selectoptions\"> </div>");
obj.find('option').each(function(i){ 
  $(".selectoptions").append("<div id=\"" + $(this).attr("value") + "\" class=\"selectitems\"><span>" + $(this).html() + "</span></div>");
});
obj.before("<input type=\"hidden\" value =\"\" name=\"" + this.name + "\" class=\"customselect\"/><div class=\"iconselect\">" + this.title + "</div><div class=\"iconselectholder\"> </div>")
.remove();
$('.iconselectholder').hide();
$(".iconselect").click(function(){
$(".iconselectholder").toggle("slow");});
    $(".iconselectholder").append( $(".selectoptions")[0] );
$(".selectitems").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hoverclass");
});
    $(".selectitems").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hoverclass");
    });
    $(".selectitems").click(function(){
    $(".selectedclass").removeClass("selectedclass");
    $(this).addClass("selectedclass");
    var thisselection = $(this).html();
$(".customselect").val(this.id);
    $(".iconselect").html(thisselection);
    $(".iconselectholder").toggle("slow")
    });
    });  
  // do the rest of the plugin, using url and settings
}
```

I am struggling to see any reason as to why my second ajax request is running the method of the first ajax request.

Comment: Format your HTML so we can better help you

Comment: The new HTML isn't nested within the .career_select .selectitems div is it?

Comment: not following you, the .selectitems is nested the in .grade_options

Comment: Unbind the original click event in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems somewhat incomplete, but I think I can help you.

Where is the class `.career_select` in the HTML+PHP example you have given?  My guess is that `.career_select` is wrapping `.grade_options` due to your append: 
**$('.hfeed').append(html)** am I correct?  `.grade_options` was part of the html that got appended right?

If I am correct, then the newly appended HTML would not have had event handlers tied to it ahead of time and hence your second event handler is not firing.  I think there are two things you can do:

1. Declare the new event handler for $('.grade_options .selectitems') in the success function of the first event handler AFTER the append.

If that doesn't work then just do what Paul Sweatte instructed you to do (look at the comments), unbind the original click event in the success callback or if you are sure it is a one-off thing, take a look at jQuery's $(selector).one().

I hope this helps.  If the second one works, please remember to give points to Paul Sweatte's comment.